# select 3 values for each id based on top values in a count column

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I select across multiple rows based on a particular column value. For example I have a structure like this

```
+--+----+-----+
|id|data|count|
+--+----+-----+
|1 |text|30   |
+--+----+-----+
|1 |text|1    |
+--+----+-----+
|1 |text|25   |
+--+----+-----+
|1 |text|12   |
+--+----+-----+
|1 |text|50   |
+--+----+-----+
|2 |text|5    |
+--+----+-----+
|2 |text|2    |
+--+----+-----+
|2 |text|100  |
+--+----+-----+
|2 |text|50   |
+--+----+-----+
|2 |text|1000 |
+--+----+-----+
|3 |text|2    |
+--+----+-----+
|3 |text|4    |
+--+----+-----+
|3 |text|6    |
+--+----+-----+
|3 |text|8    |
+--+----+-----+
```

And I want to select three of every ID--the "top" 3 based on the highest values in the `count` column so that I'll end up with:

```
+--+----+-----+
|id|data|count|
+--+----+-----+
|1 |text|30   |
+--+----+-----+
|1 |text|25   |
+--+----+-----+
|1 |text|50   |
+--+----+-----+
|2 |text|100  |
+--+----+-----+
|2 |text|50   |
+--+----+-----+
|2 |text|1000 |
+--+----+-----+
|3 |text|4    |
+--+----+-----+
|3 |text|6    |
+--+----+-----+
|3 |text|8    |
+--+----+-----+
```

I am essentially stuck on the first WHERE clause: I don't want the rows where `count` is above a particular value as that could return more than 3 results. I can do a limit 3 and sort by count, but that will only work for one id. How can I do this for every distinct id in my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to implement a [windowing function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) like `row_number()` to get the top 3 for each `id`:

```
select id, data, "count"
from 
(
  select id, data, "count",
    row_number() over(partition by id order by "count" desc) seq
  from yourtable
) d
where seq <= 3
order by id, "count";
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/41c9f/2)

Comment: why is `count` in quotes?

Comment: @thomas the sql fiddle added them when I created the DDL. `count` might be a reserved word so I was escaping the name.  I am not familiar with the reserved word list in postgresql, but if it reserved then you will need to escape the name.

Comment: This is super slick and totally amazing. Do you mind explaining a bit how it works? Thanks very much!

Comment: @thomas windowing functions like row_number are useful since you can create a unique sequence for a partition - in your case by `id`.  The sequence is then created for each unique id based on the order that you give it - again `order by count desc`. There are other windowing functions (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) that could be used based on your needs like `rank()` and `dense_rank` - here is a tutorial that will help -- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Pro tip: you can replace the version number in postgresql.org documentation links with `current` to get the latest version of the docs rather than ancient (8.4) or slightly ripe (9.1) versions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for the tip, postgresql is not my area of expertise. :)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6bc64/1 I've tried to expand this a bit so I could start to use it, but for some reason I only get two results for `test4`. Why would this be?

Comment: @thomas move your `company_id` filter to the subquery -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6bc64/5

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT "id",data,"count"
FROM  
  (SELECT "id",data,"count" rank() OVER (partition by "id" ORDER BY "count" DESC) as rn 
  FROM 
  your_table) t
WHERE  rn <= 3
ORDER BY "id","count" desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PARTITION BY and RANK() function . [See here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)